# deploy project on my local machine with Apache

Tags: django, apache, godaddy-api

I built a website with Django, installed Apache and made all the adjustments.
In addition, I bought a domain from GoDaddy for the site.
I want to deploy the site on my computer.
The problem is when I try to access the site via the internet I get to a page from GoDaddy with my domain.

The steps I did:

1. Add A record with my local IP DNS on GoDaddy
2. Installing wsgi
3. Updating the settings.py page with the new addresses.
4. Update httpd-vhosts
5. Update httpd.conf
6. Resetting the Apache server
7. open the ports in my firewall

*I bought the domain two days ago.

httpd.conf:
ServerName DomainName
LoadFile path
LoadModule wsgi_module path
WSGIPythonHome path

httpd-vhosts:
ServerName DomainName
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName DomainName
ServerAlias www.DomainName

```
WSGIScriptAlias / "path"
ErrorLog "logs/DomainName-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/DomainName-access.log" common

<Directory "path">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static "path"
<Directory "path">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Local IP? You need to provide yours external IP address to record A. And redirect port 80 on your router to point to your pc. Also you need to allow port 80 on Windows firewall.

Comment: @WaldemarPodsiadło
I mean to the external IP address and I and  also opened ports in firewall and in the router.
Something I don't understand about the address, what address should I provide to GoDaddy ?
The address that the router assigns to me? (But every time the computer turns on, the router assigns a new address)
Or the address of the router (Gateway)?